# Literal string union autocomplete in Typescript 3.8.3

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to add autocompletion support to my function that accepts either a literal union of known object keys, a string, or a RegExp. Because TS collapses the union of strings into a string type I needed a trick to get autocompletion to work for the known keys but also allow arbitrary strings to be passed in. I found several solutions online like the ones mentioned in this [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29729), but the problem is, none of them work in my TS version `3.8.3`. This is what I have

[link to ts playgrounds](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.8.3#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgQwHZIgGwKIDcJOABQRDQHsEATAWQTCgF4oAlCAYxICdyAeAZ2HYCWSAOYAaJqw7c+gkeOQgAfIoCwAKHWhIsRCnQBBAK7ASbALZg0EYBC7xkqNNVoQAHjaTkeOh+my4CIlIKZ0V6dShIqAAfKABrCBASADMfPScaCKjYgAoZIWEoADIoAG8AXwBKLMjY5mEMVzB1dRY0BB5vABkBPlwIdjtdR2coNw8vNMd-PEJiMioaMNKaqDRejzsx91xJ+3SjE3NLa1t9kaXFPMNhYQg+ARIkHgAuWEqy8vUvjTU2Z+Aaw2-XY9CgqAA7lAen1UINSlAWLo3giIFg3khDGYAEYDKDlADciN0ACYUWN0VBsSQSFZkPj8Vdqmp1rCBgA6VkeHIAIh5HwA9AKoAAREj3JAAckBCGMphIFisNigYHYJEg7DQICgTygAGZ2QAOPVYKnGKAQjhxby6rAAFnZAHZ2XaANRAA)

```js
type ChannelEventPayloadMap = Record<string, Record<string, any>>

type ChannelAutocomplete<ChannelMap extends ChannelEventPayloadMap> =
    | keyof ChannelMap
    | (string & {})
    | RegExp

class Listener<ChannelMap extends ChannelEventPayloadMap> {
    listen<C extends ChannelAutocomplete<ChannelMap>>(suggestions: C) {}
}

const listener = new Listener<{ chan: { ev: number }; chan2: { ev: boolean } }>()
hub.listen("") // Doesn't autocomplete properly on v3.83 but works on v4.7.4+
```

I tried using `Record<never, never>`, `type AnyString = string & {Idk?: any}`, `type LiteralUnion<T extends U, U = string> = T | (U & { zz_IGNORE_ME?: never })` and so on, but these don't seem to work in my case, even though Typescript version of their suggestions and mine are similar. Also tried something along the lines of

```
type ChannelAutocomplete<ChannelMap extends ChannelEventPayloadMap> = {
  [K in keyof ChannelMap]: K;
}[keyof ChannelMap];
```

But this also didn't do the trick. Probably during my experimentations I lost some key part that would've made it work but I am now out of ideas. Not sure how `v3.8.3` behaves, as I've only used `v4.5+`, and updating the version is not an option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

union it with keys for autocompletion

```
type ChannelEventPayloadMap = Record<string, Record<string, any>>

type ChannelAutocomplete<ChannelMap extends ChannelEventPayloadMap> =
    | keyof ChannelMap
    | (string & {})
    | RegExp

class Listener<ChannelMap extends ChannelEventPayloadMap> {
    listen<C extends ChannelAutocomplete<ChannelMap>>(
        suggestions: C | ChannelAutocomplete<ChannelMap> // <- union with all types
    ) {}
    listen2<C extends ChannelAutocomplete<ChannelMap>>(
        suggestions: C | keyof ChannelMap // <- union with autocomplete types
    ) {}
}

const listener = new Listener<{ chan: { ev: number }; chan2: { ev: boolean } }>()
listener.listen("chan") // DOES autocomplete properly on 3.83v
listener.listen2('chan') // DOES autocomplete properly on 3.83v
```

---

Notes:

This works by adding autocompletion cases into the parameter itself: TS3.8.3 can't *infer* them from generic, because it gets merged with `string & {}` for whatever reason. Adding cases to parameter makes current overload accept `<''>('' | 'chan')` making `'chan'` autocompleteable.
Just overloads don't work as well, because autocompletion gets limited to the `string & {}` overload.

Be careful with the fact you can call it with a different type if you provide generic type: `listener.listen<'blah'>('chan')`

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working properly. Can you expand a bit on why it works and if there are any things to be aware of? I'll accept it as the answer, so thanks a lot!

Comment: @Nikola-Milovic added notes